# Compare portions of files

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have 5 files

```
file1 - 32 bytes
file2 - 32 bytes
file3 - 32 bytes
file4 - 32 bytes

file5 - 128 bytes
```

I would like to compare if data matches between

```
file1 - first 32 bytes of file5
file2 - 2nd 32 bytes of file 5 i.e from 32- 64 bytes
file3-  3rd 32 bytes of file 5 i.e from 64-96 bytes 
file4-  4th 32 bytes of file5 i.e from 96 -128 bytes
```

I am able to compare the first 32 bytes using

```
cmp -n 32 file1.txt file5.txt
```

But stuck up on other 3 data comparsions ? Can someone please help me out here ?

Answer (score 4):

- **With `dd`**

Extract parts by skipping blocks.

```
 dd bs=32 count=1 skip=1 if=file5 | diff - file2
```

Increase the number of skipped blocks accordingly to match the other files.

- **With `split`**

The files are small and won't take much space. Split the big one in bits and compare them:

```
split -b 32 file5
diff xab file2
```

- **all at once**

Maybe they all match? Of course, this will miss if only one of them does not match:

```
 cat file{1..4}  | diff  - file5
```

---

Of course, `cmp` instead of `diff' would work, too.